# Apache unwanted redirecting

Tags: apache, redirect

Apache on ubuntu 11.04 is displaying /tag/ using the /tag.php file. I suspect that this would be the preferred behavior most of the time, but in this case I dislike the effects it has. How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but check whether content autonegotiation is enabled and try disabling it.

Comment: That was it, thanks. Post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have "content-negotiation" enables. That's a feature that lets the server deduce the file name from just the un-suffixed name depending on the requested client preferences, which can cause the behaviour you describe.